# What's the term for interchanging a frequently used machine with a seldomly used one?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to find out the term used for the practice of interchanging/relocating/swapping 2 machines to compensate the wear and tear caused by the operation frequency differences between them. This is a practice used in machine plants where a bunch of similar machines are being utilized and where some machines get used more than the others. For example coin store laundries do swap their most used machines with the ones getting less attention because they are located at the back of these stores.

I'm told that there's a term for this practice.

Comment: The words 'balancing' and 'rotation' come to mind, but as soon as you include the word 'machine' with them in a google search, everything gets buried under links about wheel balancing and rotating machinery generally...

Comment: Yes, that is called rotation, but it needs a little help from context.

Comment: Would the terms "Rotational Machine Load Balancing" or "Load Balancing Machine Rotation"  give a clear message? What do you understand when you hear these terms?